# What is the ratio/formula to use to circumbscribe a icosahedron it in a unit sphere?

Tags: geometry

Given a icosahedron with side edge length of $a$, and its $12$ vertices coordinates in 3D, how can I calculate the new length $\hat a$ so that the icosahedron will fit into a unit sphere with its vertices touching the surface of the sphere?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2538184/proof-of-golden-rectangle-inside-an-icosahedron

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_icosahedron#Dimensions

Comment: Given a "golden" rectangle with center at the origin, you can explicitly relate the shorter edge of the rectangle, which will be the edge length for the icosahedron, with half the length of a diagonal of the rectangle, which will be your sphere radius.